# Preferred way to write audio data to a WAV file?

Tags: python, numpy, wav, wave

I am trying to write an audio file using python's `wave` and `numpy`. So far I have the following and it works well:

```py
import wave
import numpy as np

# set up WAV file parameters
num_channels    = 1                             # mono audio
sample_width    = 1                             # 8 bits(1 byte)/sample
sample_rate     = 44.1e3                        # 44.1k samples/second
frequency       = 440                           # 440 Hz
duration        = 20                            # play for this many seconds
num_samples     = int(sample_rate * duration)   # samples/seconds * seconds

# open WAV file and write data
with wave.open('sine8bit_2.wav', 'w') as wavfile:
    wavfile.setnchannels(num_channels)
    wavfile.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    wavfile.setframerate(sample_rate)

    t = np.linspace(0, duration, num_samples)
    data = (127*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t)).astype(np.int8)
    wavfile.writeframes(data) # or data.tobytes() ??
```

My issue is that since I am using a high sampling rate, the `num_samples` variable might quickly become too large (9261000 samples for a 3 minute 30 seconds track say). Would using a numpy array this large be advisable? Is there a better way of going about this? Also is use of `writeframes(.tobytes())` needed in this case because my code runs fine without it and it seems like extra overhead (especially if the arrays get too large).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only going to write a sine wave, you could very well create only one period as your `data` array and write that several times to the `.wav` file.

Using the parameters you provided, your `data` array is 8800 times smaller with that approach. Its size also no longer depends on the duration of your file!

```py
import wave
import numpy as np

# set up WAV file parameters
num_channels    = 1                             # mono audio
sample_width    = 1                             # 8 bits(1 byte)/sample
sample_rate     = 44.1e3                        # 44.1k samples/second
frequency       = 440                           # 440 Hz
duration        = 20                            # play for this many seconds

# Create a single period of sine wave.
n = round(sample_rate/frequency)
t = np.linspace(0, 1/frequency, n)
data = (127*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t)).astype(np.int8)
periods = round(frequency*duration)

# open WAV file and write data
with wave.open('sine8bit_2.wav', 'w') as wavfile:
    wavfile.setnchannels(num_channels)
    wavfile.setsampwidth(sample_width)
    wavfile.setframerate(sample_rate)

    for _ in range(periods):
        wavfile.writeframes(data)
```